# Is there a way to overload map.resources in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to create clean urls in rails.  I have installed PermalinkFu and I can generate the links just fine.  What I would like to do is keep my RESTful resource.  Is there a way I can overload:

```
map.resources :location
```

to return :permalink variable instead of :id?

Similar to how I can create:

```
map.connect 'location/:permalink' :controller => 'location', :action => 'show'
```

**A side note:**  What is the best practice for handling permalinks, should they only used to display the view/show action then use the :id for edit/destroy/etc? And should I even be concerned with the controller using :id instead of :permalink as a variable name?

Answer (score 2):

It's my way to solve this problem:

use to_param method in your model Location:

```
def to_param
  permalink
end
```

and in your routes.rb

```
map.resources :location
```

There is no need to add a rule for permalink

then you can find in your controller like this

```
@location = Location.find_by_permalink params[:id]
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Right, the above is what I have now and am trying to change. 

This doesn't seem sloppy to anyone?  Using the params[:id] variable when you are really passing params[:permalink]?  

What I'd like to do is have the map.resources :location populate the params[:permalink] var instead of params[:id]

Comment: Personally I think it's a very minor concern.

Comment: This has always seemed sloppy to me.  I've been grumbling about it for forever.  :)

Comment: @Ian ya right now I'm just runing with params[:id], I don't like it but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for an answer to this question as well. :path_prefix seems to be the thing that should solve this problem, but I don't understand how it should be used.

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/7fc46fd8e354792b/3e364626d9d67403?lnk=gst&q=restful+two+parameters

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't override the `to_param` method in your `Location` model? Ryan Bates has a [Railscast that explains how to do this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url).

If you want to be a purist then you should use the permalink for all the actions, but it's undoubtedly more convenient to use the numeric ID for the edit and destroy actions. I guess it depends if you're bothered by people viewing the HTML and being able to see the actual primary keys of your records. Some might consider that a security hole.